# Solve the following problem related to hemisphere

Tags: calculus

> **Question:** A hemispherical bowl is being filled with water at a constant volumetric rate. The level of water in the bowl increases
>
> 1. in direct proportion to time,
> 2. in inverse  proportion to time,
> 3. faster than direct proportion to time,
> 4. slower than direct  proportion to time

To solve this problem, let us consider a hemisphere with radius $r$ and volume $V$. Then  $V=\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$. This implies $\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$. Is it possible to solve the problem in this way? I don't know how to find the condition. Please suggest.

Comment: The radius of the hemisphere does not change or does it?

Answer (score 2):

What is important is not so much the radius of the hemisphere as the radius of the top surface of the water.  Let's call that $R(t)$ If you add a volume $v$ of water, it raises the depth by about $\frac v{\pi R(t)^2}$ (ignoring the small increase in the radius).  As $R(t)$ is increasing, the rate the depth increases is decreasing.  This will be true in any bowl that has the sides going outward.

Answer (score 2):

The volumetric rate ( say in $ft^3/s$ ) is at every moment 
$\frac{d V}{dt} = \frac{d h}{dt} \cdot \text{Area of cross section}$.

If the volumetric rate is constant then the rate of change of the height at a certain moment is inverse proportional to the cross section at that moment.

Since the cross section is increasing as $h$ is increasing ( hemisphere), the rate of change of $h$ is decreasing ( while still being positive), so $h$ is growing slower than direct proportional to time.